# What is the difference between ham, bacon, and gammon?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, american-english, british-english

The OED defines ***ham*** as:

*The thigh of a slaughtered animal, used for food; spec. that of a hog salted and dried in smoke or otherwise; also, the meat so prepared.*

It defines ***gammon*** as:

*The bottom piece of a side or flitch of bacon, including the hind leg. In later use also: a smoked or cured ham.*

It defines ***bacon*** as:

*The back and sides of the pig, ‘cured’ by salting, drying, etc. Formerly also the fresh flesh now called pork.*

In Britain there is a street-wisdom about when to describe meat as *ham*, as *bacon* or *gammon*. Ham is usually bought ready-cooked. *Gammon* usually comes as a joint, *bacon* in slices.

But is there a clear distinction which is not being picked up here?

Comment: My understanding is: Ham and gammon both come from hind legs and are cured meat, but gammon is the raw state. Bacon is cured meat from the back and belly.

Comment: In the US, bacon is "pork belly", cured, smoked, and optionally sliced.  Not really part of the "ham".  Not sure I've ever heard "gammon".

Comment: @Spagirl - Ham is generally "raw" as well.

Comment: @Spagirl Yes, I think you are right about "gammon" being the raw state. But also when eaten hot, it is more inclined to be called "gammon". Why don't you put your comment into an answer? I think you are right.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, America has never heard of back-bacon, as I always discover when I'm there. In fact the only countries where I have ever been served lean bacon, outside the UK are the Republic of Ireland and Australia. No doubt there are others. You only eat the fat stuff from around the belly.

Comment: @WS2 - It's known as "Canadian bacon".

Comment: @HotLicks Like the Australians, and the Irish the Canadians also no doubt know all about proper bacon. I explained to a chef in an Italian hotel this summer, that he was serving American bacon, and explained one easy step to improving his breakfast menu - acquire some proper bacon.

Comment: I didn't realize *gammon* was specific to hogs, I thought it just meant a haunch of anything. Turns out it used to mean animal leg, but in Latin, and a long time ago. I think haunch is the American equivalent, though. Pork butt also serves.

Comment: @WS2 - Pretty soon you will be complaining about lobsters.

Comment: @PhilSweet But to be *gammon*, in British parlance, it has to be cured.

Comment: @WS2 We are aware of the problem, but are concentrating on fixing our beer first, which we are having some luck with. I will suggest that we tackle bacon next.

Comment: @HotLicks I dont think British usage allows for raw 'ham', though you could probably have 'a' raw ham. I'm not sure what to take from your inverted commas though, does "raw" differ from 'raw'? Gammon and ham are essentially the same word if you think of the ways 'jamón' can be borrowed.

Comment: @Spagirl - I've no idea what British usage is, but in the US "ham", as purchased in a hunk (vs sliced for sandwiches) is generally uncooked (though it usually has been smoked/cured).  However, it probably is getting to the point that half the ham in groceries anymore is "precooked", as a convenience (though one must read the label to be sure).

Comment: @WS2 Is it worth sticking a british-english tag on this since the US differentiates differently and doesn't apparently use 'gammon'?

Comment: @Spagirl Yes, I will do that.

Comment: @WS2 While Americans may not have heard of back-bacon or gammon, I’m fairly sure they have generally heard of backgammon. ;-)

Comment: @Spagirl If you asked for "uncooked ham" in Britain, they would know what you meant. In fact I'm fairly sure some shops call it that - though I can't find any on the Tesco site. When eaten hot, I believe it normally gets called "ham" if it's in slices, but "gammon" if it is served as a steak with a pineapple ring or an egg on top.

Comment: @WS2 Perhaps it's regional (and of course you can understand what is meant by a term without that term being in habitual use, 'uncooked scrambled egg' perhaps is close?). IME, only the 'count noun' can be uncooked 'an uncooked ham', where as *ham* is always cooked.

Comment: Did someone mention ‘spiny’ or ‘Boston’ lobsters? Or was that crawfish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following extract tries to outline the main differences:

From [SeedToFeedMe](http://seedtofeedme.blogspot.it/2013/02/what-is-difference-between-gammon-ham.html):

> - Gammon, ham and bacon are all cured meats (which means they are preserved using salt or brine), and all can be smoked. However there are some key differences between them.
> - ***The main difference between gammon and ham is that gammon is sold raw and needs to be cooked, whilst ham is sold cooked and ready for eating.*** Therefore it is true that a gammon is a ham that has not yet been cooked. If a gammon is prepared and cooked it can be called a ham, and is generally sold as a gammon ham.
> - ***Gammon and bacon are both cured pork. The main difference between them is the part of the pig from which they originate.*** Gammon is the hind leg (haunch) of a pig whilst bacon is the meat from other parts of the pig such as the loin, collar or belly.

[image]